# Compare cells and color matching words

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have sentence in A column and I have sentence in B column. I want to match A1 and B1 and color red to the words which are matching.
For example:

```
A1: Lenovo T450 with 5 GB RAM, Intel i5 CPU, 500 GB HDD, 14" HD screen, weight 3.5 pounds

B1: 5 GB  i5 CPU, 500 GB HDD, 14" HD 3.5
```

Then I want to color red the words are matching with B1.

Answer (score 1):

**Remade 9/2, useless codes scrapped**

You can try this:

```
Sub sameStringRed()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, intStart As Integer
Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
Dim strDelimit As String: strDelimit = " "

For Each rngA In Selection.Rows
    Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)
    On Error GoTo Error
    strA = Split(rngA.Text, strDelimit)
    strB = Split(rngB.Text, strDelimit)
    For j = LBound(strA) To UBound(strA)
        For i = LBound(strB) To UBound(strB)
            If strA(j) = strB(i) Then
                intStart = InStr(1, UCase(rngA.Value), UCase(strB(i)))
                While intStart > 0
                    If Mid(rngA, intStart + Len(strB(i)), 1) = strDelimit Or Mid(rngA, intStart + Len(strB(i)), 1) = "" Then
                        rngA.Characters(Start:=intStart, Length:=Len(strB(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    End If
                    intStart = InStr(intStart + 1, UCase(rngA.Value), UCase(strB(i)))
                Wend
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
Next
Exit Sub
Error:
MsgBox "Please do not select multiple columns"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Wow!! I got hope that my issue will get resolved. This macro is working partially for my requirement. I want A1 to match with B1 and color red to the words in A1, Next A2 to match with B2 and color red to the words in A2 like this it should repeat till data contains of A column. I am new to VB so please can you help me on this.

Comment: @Lokesh Updated it to work correctly, and then added a sub to loop it through multiple cells.

Comment: Scrapped the extra sub and just merged it together.

Comment: Unfortunately its not working fine for me. Its working correctly for first 3 rows 4th row everything changed to red and macro stops with error. "Run time error 6 - overflow". Please can you send different one,.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake!! Your macro is working absolutely fine. You are genius. It is so helpful for me. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Lokesh Thank you. Mind telling me what you did to get the error?
I didn't do any proper error handling in the code, so I'm quite sure you can break it in a few ways (like selecting multiple columns, I should've done error handling for that).
Also, feel free to mark the question answered if you are pleased with the answer. 
And comment if there is anything else you need.

Comment: I have got one more problem with this macro and I need your help. Example Cell: (A1 = Period per day and B1 = per) when i run the macro it is coloring both Period and per word but i want it to color only per. please can you modify and send it to me.

Comment: @Lokesh Try the completely different code that edited in the answer. It's a bit experimental, but not much more so than the first one. Seems to work pretty good, at least on single words.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. the code you are given is partially fulfilled my requirement. Example Cell: (A1 = "Period per day of the week" and B1 = "PER DAY WEEK") then i want macro to color "per day week" word in cell A1. At present it is coloring only "per" word. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: And one more thing sometimes matching cell (Ex;B1) will be empty. that time it can skip that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Lokesh I managed to figure it out I think. Check the last edited version. It skips empty "B" rows and should color all the words properly.

Comment: thanks a lot, its working absolutely fine as i wanted. You are genius.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. The code what you are given is working fine but i need one additional help. Example Cell: A1 = 44+ (BB) and B1 = 44+ (BB) in this case the query is not coloring because of the special character, can you please modify and provide the updated query.

Comment: @Lokesh I can't make it so that it works consistently with special characters with regexp.
I updated the original code to skip partial matches, and it should work a lot better with special characters.