# Compare 2 cell and highlight match words

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have sentence in A column and I have sentence in B column. I want to match A1 and B1 and color red to the words which are matching. For example:

A1: `Lenovo T450 with 5 GB RAM Intel i5 CPU 500 GB HDD 14" HD screen, weight 3.5 pounds (90)`

B1: `Len 5 GB h i5 CPU 500 GB HDD 14" HD 3.5 (90)`

And i want to color red the below words in A1 cell - `5 GB i5 CPU 500 GB HDD 14" HD 3.5 (90)`

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer at http://superuser.com/questions/1143443/compare-cells-and-color-matching-words ?

Comment: Yes it is not working as i wanted.... it is coloring "h" in "with" word because there is h in B1 cell but i wanted it to color only exact match and it should color (90), 14" also.

Comment: Not really no. Go back and try it. It doesn't highlight incomplete matches and does work with special characters. 
In your example, the colored text will be: 

5 GB i5 CPU 500 GB HDD 14" HD 3.5 (90)

Comment: As per the above example it is not coloring "with" but incase if A1 = "Lenovo T450 with h 5 GB RAM Intel i5 CPU 500 GB HDD 14" HD screen, weight 3.5 pounds (90)"   then it is coloring with because i have added "h" in A1. and same time i want it to work with special characters also. please can you modify and send the updated macro for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my previous answer, there was a bug that i missed.
In the rare cases a word was followed by the same letter it was ending with, while only that letter was being searched for, then both the ending letter and the following letter was colored.

Here is an updated answer:

First, we write the sub and some variables that we will need:

```
Sub sameStringRed()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, intStart As Integer
Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
Dim strDelimit As String: strDelimit = " "
```

The strDelimit variable determines what separates the words from each other and can be changed to something like ", " if needed.

Then we proceed with setting our ranges as needed.

```
For Each rngA In Selection.Rows
    Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)
    strA = Split(rngA.Text, strDelimit)
    strB = Split(rngB.Text, strDelimit)
 Next
```

Each selected row in a column will be `rngA` and each row in the column next to it will be `rngB`.
Then an array is created with the `Split` function, with one entry for each word in each cell.

Next we proceed with comparing the two arrays:

```
For j = LBound(strA) To UBound(strA)
    For i = LBound(strB) To UBound(strB)
        If UCase(strA(j)) = UCase(strB(i)) Then
            intStart = InStr(1, strDelimit + UCase(rngA.Value) + strDelimit, strDelimit + UCase(strB(i)) + strDelimit)

        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

This will take each entry in each array and compare them with each other.
And if they are identical, the variable `intStart` will be set to the position of the first matching word in the cell `rngA` *the selected cell*.
*Now with **strDelimit** added on both sides to make sure it's not another word ending or starting with the same thing being searched for.*

Now we need to actually do something with that information, so within the previous `if` statement, we can use the folowing:

```
While intStart > 0
    rngA.Characters(Start:=intStart, Length:=Len(strB(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
    intStart = InStr(intStart + 1, strDelimit + UCase(rngA.Value) + strDelimit, strDelimit + UCase(strB(i)) + strDelimit)
Wend
```

Here we simply set the color of the characters in the selected cell to index 3, which is red.
Then we add +1 to intStart, and run the check again to see if we have any more matching words.

A minor problem now is that

```
For Each rngA In Selection.Rows
    Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)
```

will trow an error if multiple columns are selected.

To deal with this we can add a simple error handling with the use of `On Error GoTo Error`

The final code will then look like the following: 
**Edit** Missed case sensitive and re-added a control function.

```
Sub sameStringRed()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, intStart As Integer
Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
Dim strDelimit As String: strDelimit = " "

For Each rngA In Selection.Rows
    Set rngB = rngA.Offset(0, 1)
    On Error GoTo Error
    strA = Split(rngA.Text, strDelimit)
    strB = Split(rngB.Text, strDelimit)
    For j = LBound(strA) To UBound(strA)
        For i = LBound(strB) To UBound(strB)
            If UCase(strA(j)) = UCase(strB(i)) Then
                intStart = InStr(1, strDelimit + UCase(rngA.Value) + strDelimit, strDelimit + UCase(strB(i)) + strDelimit)
                While intStart > 0
                    rngA.Characters(Start:=intStart, Length:=Len(strB(i))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    intStart = InStr(intStart + 1, strDelimit + UCase(rngA.Value) + strDelimit, strDelimit + UCase(strB(i)) + strDelimit)

                Wend
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
Next
Exit Sub
Error:
MsgBox "Please do not select multiple columns"
End Sub
```

And the result should look like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Before it was coloring the last letter of the word now it is coloring the first letter. Example A1 = T450 with HDD Screen 14" (90) h r and B1 = T450 h R 14" (90) then its coloring H in HDD word and one more problem is i dont want case sensitive it should color if it is matching even lower or upper case. In my example it is not coloring "r" because it is in lower case. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Lokesh Fine, change `If strA(j) = strB(i) Then` to `If UCase(strA(j)) = UCase(strB(i))` Then for non-case sensitive. and add `+ strDelimit` after every `Ucase` in the `intStart` calculation.
Code is updated.

Comment: Its working fine now, Thanks for all your support.